# How can I get the label text to the left of the input field?

Tags: html, css

I am not able to understand how I can get the label from top of the input field to the left. The label text is on top of the input field. How can I get it to the left of the input field for the contact information part? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

This is my code:

```css
#p1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

#h31 {
  text-align: center;
}

#p2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

 ::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #3cbc8d;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="email"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#p3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#submitdiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#textareadiv {
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[id="zipcode"] {
  width: 40%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .formcenter {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  form {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  select {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #p1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">

<p id="p1">THE CODE REVIEW</p><br><br>
<div class="formcenter">
  <form method="post" action="project3.html">
    <h3 id="h31">Sign up for our newsletter</h3>
    <p id="p2">Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3 id="h32">Contact Information</h3>
      </legend>
      <label for="inputfield">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield">
      <label for="inputfield1">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield1">
      <label for="inputfield2">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="inputfield2">
      <label for="inputfield3">Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="streetaddress" id="inputfield3">
      <label for="inputfield4">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" id="inputfield4">
      <label for="stateselect">State</label>
      <select name="state" id="stateselect">
    <option>Choose State</option>
    <option value="mah">Maharashtra</option>
    <option value="guj">Gujarat</option>
    <option value="pun">Punjab</option>
    </select>
      <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode">
    </fieldset>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
      </legend><br>
      <label>Select the newsletters you would like to receive</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="htmlnews"><label>HTML News</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="css"><label>CSS News</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="javascript"><label>Javascript News</label><br><br>
      <label>Newsletter format</label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="html"><label>HTML</label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="plaintext"><label>Plain Text</label><br><br>
      <label>Other topics you'd like to hear about</label><br><br>
      <div id="textareadiv">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
      </div>
      <div id="submitdiv">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br><br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p id="p3"><i>Copyright The Code Review</i></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display:flex with a container for each lines

```css
.line
{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.line label
{
  min-width:200px;
}


input
{
  flex:1;
  margin:10px;
}


#p1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

#h31 {
  text-align: center;
}

#p2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

 ::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #3cbc8d;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="email"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#p3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#submitdiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#textareadiv {
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[id="zipcode"] {
  width: 40%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .formcenter {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  form {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  select {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #p1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">

<p id="p1">THE CODE REVIEW</p><br><br>
<div class="formcenter">
  <form method="post" action="project3.html">
    <h3 id="h31">Sign up for our newsletter</h3>
    <p id="p2">Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3 id="h32">Contact Information</h3>
      </legend>
      
      <div class="line">
        <label for="inputfield">Full Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield">
      </div>
      
      <div class="line">
        <label for="inputfield1">Email Address :</label>
        <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield1">
      </div>
      
      <div class="line">
        <label for="inputfield2">Phone Number :</label>
        <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="inputfield2">
      </div>
      
      <div class="line">
        <label for="inputfield3">Street Address :</label>
        <input type="text" name="streetaddress" id="inputfield3">
      </div>
      
      <div class="line">
        <label for="inputfield4">City :</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="inputfield4">
      </div>
      
      <div class="line">
          <label for="stateselect">State :</label>
          <select name="state" id="stateselect">

        <option>Choose State</option>
        <option value="mah">Maharashtra</option>
        <option value="guj">Gujarat</option>
        <option value="pun">Punjab</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="zipcode">Zip Code :</label>
      <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
      </legend><br>
      <label>Select the newsletters you would like to receive</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="htmlnews"><label>HTML News</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="css"><label>CSS News</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="javascript"><label>Javascript News</label><br><br>
      <label>Newsletter format</label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="html"><label>HTML</label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="plaintext"><label>Plain Text</label><br><br>
      <label>Other topics you'd like to hear about</label><br><br>
      <div id="textareadiv">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
      </div>
      <div id="submitdiv">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br><br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p id="p3"><i>Copyright The Code Review</i></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset width and `display` on `inputs` and/or use `float`.

It can be a reset at any time or within the `mediaquerie`.

You can also filter within which `fieldset` you need this reset to be effective.*(example below)*

```
  .formcenter  fieldset:first-of-type label,
  .formcenter  fieldset:first-of-type input{
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .formcenter fieldset:first-of-type label {
    clear: left;
    width: 35%;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"],
  input[type="radio"]{
    margin-right:1em;
  }
  fieldset ~ fieldset br + label {
    margin:1em;
    color:gray
  }
```

```css
#p1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

#h31 {
  text-align: center;
}

#p2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

 ::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #3cbc8d;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="email"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#p3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#submitdiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#textareadiv {
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[id="zipcode"] {
  width: 40%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .formcenter {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  form {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  select {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #p1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .formcenter  fieldset:first-of-type label,
  .formcenter  fieldset:first-of-type input{
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .formcenter fieldset:first-of-type label {
    clear: left;
    width: 35%;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"],
  input[type="radio"]{
    margin-right:1em;
  }
  fieldset ~ fieldset br + label {
    margin:1em;
    color:gray
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">

<p id="p1">THE CODE REVIEW</p><br><br>
<div class="formcenter">
  <form method="post" action="project3.html">
    <h3 id="h31">Sign up for our newsletter</h3>
    <p id="p2">Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3 id="h32">Contact Information</h3>
      </legend>
      <label for="inputfield">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield">
      <label for="inputfield1">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield1">
      <label for="inputfield2">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="inputfield2">
      <label for="inputfield3">Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="streetaddress" id="inputfield3">
      <label for="inputfield4">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" id="inputfield4">
      <label for="stateselect">State</label>
      <select name="state" id="stateselect">
    <option>Choose State</option>
    <option value="mah">Maharashtra</option>
    <option value="guj">Gujarat</option>
    <option value="pun">Punjab</option>
    </select>
      <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode">
    </fieldset>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
      </legend><br>
      <label>Select the newsletters you would like to receive</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="htmlnews"><label>HTML News</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="css"><label>CSS News</label><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="javascript"><label>Javascript News</label><br><br>
      <label>Newsletter format</label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="html"><label>HTML</label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="plaintext"><label>Plain Text</label><br><br>
      <label>Other topics you'd like to hear about</label><br><br>
      <div id="textareadiv">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
      </div>
      <div id="submitdiv">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br><br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p id="p3"><i>Copyright The Code Review</i></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is not working properly. When I am using this code, the form gets completely messed up.

Comment: @shreyan what means not properly in your eyes ? label and input are meant to be side by side ? Did you understood the code and reused the methode or did you just copy/paste it somewhere in a hudge style sheet ?

Comment: Yes. The label and input have to be side by side. The label has to be on top of the input field till 767px and at 768px or more, the label and input are meant to be side by side.

Comment: @shreyan , okay, so the reset can be taken down to the mediaquerie and selector weight to be increased. You can also select the first fieldset or the nexts where to apply these rules. (Snippet updated)

Answer (score 0):

Swap your `label`s and `input`s to get desired result:

```css
#p1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

#h31 {
  text-align: center;
}

#p2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

 ::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #3cbc8d;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="email"] {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

#p3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#submitdiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#textareadiv {
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

input[id="zipcode"] {
  width: 40%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .formcenter {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  form {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  select {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #p1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet">

<p id="p1">THE CODE REVIEW</p><br><br>
<div class="formcenter">
  <form method="post" action="project3.html">
    <h3 id="h31">Sign up for our newsletter</h3>
    <p id="p2">Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3 id="h32">Contact Information</h3>
      </legend>
      <label for="inputfield">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield">
      <label for="inputfield1">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield1">
      <label for="inputfield2">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="inputfield2">
      <label for="inputfield3">Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="streetaddress" id="inputfield3">
      <label for="inputfield4">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" id="inputfield4">
      <label for="stateselect">State</label>
      <select name="state" id="stateselect">
    <option>Choose State</option>
    <option value="mah">Maharashtra</option>
    <option value="guj">Gujarat</option>
    <option value="pun">Punjab</option>
    </select>
      <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode">
    </fieldset>
    <hr>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
      </legend><br>
      <label>Select the newsletters you would like to receive</label><br><br>
      <label>HTML News</label><input type="checkbox" name="htmlnews"><br><br>
      <label>CSS News</label><input type="checkbox" name="css"><br><br>
      <label>Javascript News</label><input type="checkbox" name="javascript"><br><br>
      <label>Newsletter format</label><br><br>
      <label>HTML</label><input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="html"><br><br>
      <label>Plain Text</label><input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="plaintext"><br><br>
      <label>Other topics you'd like to hear about</label><br><br>
      <div id="textareadiv">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
      </div>
      <div id="submitdiv">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br><br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p id="p3"><i>Copyright The Code Review</i></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily:

```
Full Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Required" id="inputfield">
```

This will just make the text appear to the left side of the input itself.

---

I used this method for a newsletter input I was doing:

```
Name: <input id="nameInput" type="text" name="name" required><br>
```

Comment: The label has to be on top of the input field till 767px and then at 768px or more, the label and input field have to be side by side. So any changes that have to be made, should be made in the css code and not in the html code.

Comment: @shreyan my mistake - this method will not work then! apologies.